# Java time instant formatting discrepancies

Tags: java, time, java-time

The way Java time handles simple things like timestamps leaves me a little taken aback. Maybe I'm doing it wrong.

I want to generate an ISO 8601 timestamp string. The obvious way would be to create an `Instance.now()` and format it use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` to format it. Except that `Instance` has no `format()` method, so I can't format it with the "instance" formatter. Imagine that.

So I have to create a `ZonedDateTime` from the instance. It shouldn't matter which zone I choose, so I choose UTC because that's what `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` is going to put it in anyway:

```
Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)
```

Now I get back a string, and obviously I want to get it back to a `ZonedDateTime` instance, because that's what I used to format it with! So I try:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)
```

It complains at me that there is no time zone information. But I used a `ZonedDateTime` to generate it --- it's not my fault that it wouldn't let me use an `Instance` to format it.

Oddly `Instance` doesn't have a `format()` method, but it does have a `parse()` method, which, again oddly, is parsed using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` (even though I can't *format* an `Instance` using that formatter).

As pointed out in the comments, I can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instance.now())` to format an instance directly, so why isn't there an `Instance.format(…)`?

So just generating and parsing a timestamp seems convoluted and inconsistent. Or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You can pass `Instant` to `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(...)`, can't you?

Comment: Ah, indeed I can! I was missing the entire `DateTimeFormatter.format(…)` method. Still, it's odd that `Instant` doesn't have a `format(…)` method if it works with `DateTimeFormatter.format(…)`. And then the other issue becomes even a greater inconsistency: I can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANCE` to format an `Instance`, but not to parse it back!

Answer (score 2):

First, you can just `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(Instant.now())`.

Next, I don't see why you expect to parse back what you've formatted. Formatting is not guaranteed to be a lossless operation. If you format a `LocalDateTime` with just the year, you wouldn't expect to parse it back to `LocalDateTime`, would you?

And of course you can parse `Instant` using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT`. `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.parse(text, Instant::from)` - this is what `Instant.parse(...)` does.

Comment: "Formatting is not guaranteed to be a lossless operation." I agree as a general statement, and I don't want to be argumentative, but what exactly did I "lose" when I formatted an `Instant` to ISO 8601 timestamp format? Don't I have 100% of the information needed to get back the original `Instant`? (I can prove it to you through some code --- some convoluted code, which is my point.)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I can pass these time objects to `DateTimeFormatter.format(…)`, so that removes part of the discrepancy. But many of the others I mention still seem to remain.

Comment: @GarretWilson Wait a second, you did not format an `Instant`, you've formatted `ZonedDateTime` and tried parsing it back with `ZonedDateTime`. And not just that but you've also used the `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` for parsing (this is where you lose timezone). So I don't understand how you can be arguing about "get back the original `Instant`" since this is clearly not what you are doing in code.

Comment: Ah, that is true---I guess I confused myself because at that point using `ZonedDateTime` seemed to be the only way to format an instant. So let me try to summarize my current view: 1) `Instant` has no `format(DateTimeFormatter formatter)` method, even though it could (and `Instant.toString()` in fact uses the the formatter under the covers); and 2) `Instant` has no `parse(CharSequence text, DateTimeFormatter formatter)` format, even though `Instant.parse(final CharSequence text)` uses a formatter under the covers. So after your clarifications, I think those are the only two inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a `format(DateTimeFormatter)` method in `Instant`, because `toString()` does the job. The `toString()` method of `Instant` is implemented as:

```
return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT.format(this);
```

Thus, all you need to do is call `instant.toString()`.

To round-trip parse this back in, simply use `parse()`:

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse(text);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you need to respecify the formatter when parsing back the string?
Can't you just do `ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp);`?